# How to Iterate Two Lists and compare the items within?

Tags: java, hibernate, list, compare

I'm almost at the end of my final project in the university, I'm trying to control my inStock with my current Stock of articles.

My stock contains the following attributes:

```
int idMercaderia;
int cantidad;
int idSucursal;
```

I have two lists that contains `Inventario` type `POJO`s:

```
List <Inventario> stock = new InventarioDAO().findAll();
List <Inventario> inStock = new ArrayList <Inventario>();
```

Before persist in the database, I want to compare the attribute `idMercaderia` in both of 'em, if they're the same don't create another entry and just add the quantity `cantidad` to the current stock and do a `saveOrUpdate()` if not just create another entry.

I'm really stuck in this part and currently run out of ideas after trying iterate both Lists but I can't figure out the stock thingy.

Any help/code will be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you implemented an equals method in Inventario. If so please show the logic of it.

Comment: `Inventario` has been generated using Reverse Engineering with MyEclipse, so I only got the Hibernate DAO's (`save()`, `delete()`, `findById()`, etc.)

Comment: org.apache.commons.beanutils [check this ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099040/find-out-the-differences-between-two-java-beans-for-version-tracking/6099386#6099386) used for comparing beans

Comment: @user2334391 thanks for sharing this, i'm enconding this right now inside my iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to implement an `equals()` method if not already happened in the `Inventario` to compare `idMercaderia` in there. then

```
for(Inventario item: stock){
   if(inStock.contains(item)){
       item.cantidad++;  
   }
}
```

Comment: This is one possible solution but makes the `equals` very context specific and hides a bit the logic in my opinion. It is also a possible source of future bugs, because someone might change the `equals` method (if we think of this as an enterprise application). So good unit testing is necessary here.

Comment: Gonna try this, but trying to `item.getCantidad()` `++` will be my problem, thank you.

Comment: @user714965 yes it hides the logic a bit, but if the `idMercaderia` is the unique identifier, there should be no problem. it would be better if java would have an Comparator-like approach for this or you have to use java 8 ;)

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Map<Integer, Inventario>` of your first list to map an `idMercaderia` to one `Inventario`. Then iterate your second list and check for each item the corresponding one in the map.

```
Map<Integer, Inventario> map = new HashMap<Integer, Inventario>();
for (Inventario item : stock) {
   map.put(item.getIdMercaderia(), item);
}
```

and

```
for (Inventario item : inStock) {
   int idMercaderia = map.getIdMercaderia();
   Inventario inventario = map.get(idMercaderia);
   if (inventario == null) {
      // error handling
      continue;
   }
   if (item.getCantidad() == inventario.getCantidad() {
      // handle 
   }
}
```

Comment: This makes senses to my toughs, I changed the `map.put(item.getIdMercaderia(), item)` to `map.put(item.getMercaderia().getId(), item)` but in the Iteration of my second List I can't afford to do `map.getIdMercaderia()`. only map methods are shown, any clue on this?

Comment: That's how a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) works. You `put` a key/value pair in and call `get(key)` to retrieve the value. So in your case `map.get(item.getMercaderia().getId())` will return the `item`.